# Printing string inputs in reverse order

Tags: c++, string, getline, output

I'm trying to build a program which outputs the inputs in reverse order until the word "stop" is entered. 
for example, if I enter

```
dog cat monkey 
desk chair 
burger cheese ham 
stop
```

it should be outputting:

```
burger cheese ham
desk chair
dog cat monkey
```

So far I have the following:

```
{
string x, y;
do {
    cin >> x;
    y = y + x;
} while (x != "stop");

int reverse = y.getNumLines();

while (reverse >= 0) {
    cout << y.getLine(reverse) << "\n";
    reverse = reverse -1;
}
return 0;    
}
```

It reads my input correctly, but for the `y.getNumlines` and `y.getLine`, I get error with no outputs. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Isnt it simpler for `y` to be  `vector<string>`? And you do realize those two functions dont exist for strings right?

Comment: sorry i do not have the knowledge on vectors yet..

Comment: Does it have to be "stop"? End of file tends to work better with everything. If it's you putting the requirements on it, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Why not swap the order you are appending?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::string x, y;
    while ( (std::getline(std::cin,x)) && x != "stop"){
        y = x + "\n" + y;  // "" + "foo bar"  2.) "second input" + "foo bar"
    }

    std::cout<< y;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will output "stop". An easy fix for that is `while ((std::cin >> x) && x != "stop")`. The other problem is that it needs to print on new lines, which requires, in its easiest form, `std::getline`.

Comment: Was just pointing out the logical error in the addition more than fixing his code :p

Comment: Well, there is the `y.getLine` part. The only problem is that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1940749, That's what the `getline` part does. It reads a line of input and stores it to `x`.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I have it running the way I wanted them to. I have a question, when Karthik said that the function, getline, wouldn't work for strings, how did it work this time?
or am I being stupid..

Comment: @user1940749, What was intended was that `std::string` doesn't have `getLine` and `getNumLines` members like you try to use in your question. Instead, `std::getline` works as a free function and `getNumLines` could be replaced by a `std::count` that counts the newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

Nico's answer might be a better path for you, but for those who prefer a more idiomatic approach, I recommend a vector of lines that you can easily print backwards once stored. The first thing would be a `Line` class that you can use to idiomatically read lines of input instead of stopping at spaces:

```
struct Line {
   std::string str;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Line &line) {
   std::getline(in, line.str);

   if (line.str == "stop") {
       in.clear(std::ios::failbit);
   }

   return in;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Line &line) {
   out << line.str;
   return out;
}
```

All our `Line` needs is a string with the actual text, and I've added input and output support for it, for the reason you'll see next. Notice that the input is through `getline` rather than `>>`. This is the main purpose of the `Line` class. I also made it fail when "stop" is entered. If that's left out, it will continue reading until the EOF.

Now you can reuse the line class with minimal effort in order to shape input however you want. Next, we get to use what we just created (or possibly had left from something else):

```
int main() {
   std::istream_iterator<Line> in1(std::cin), in2;
   std::vector<Line> inputs(in1, in2);
   std::reverse_copy(std::begin(inputs), std::end(inputs), std::ostream_iterator<Line>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

The first thing we do is form a vector by reading input (using our input support for `Line`). When the end of file is reached, or "stop" is entered, it will stop, and every line input will be nicely stored in our vector.

Next, we call `reverse_copy` to copy everything in our vector (each line of input) to the standard output, separated by newlines, but all done backwards, so we end up with every line in the reverse order.

And that's it! Once the `Line` class has been made, the algorithm for getting line inputs and reversing them can stay the same as if we were doing it with words, but the switch to lines only requires replacing a few instances of `std::string` with `Line`.

Comment: User denoted that he didn't know of vector. This hints that user's class is yet to be taught how to make classes.

Comment: @Nico, I realize that. That's why I have the note at the beginning recommending your answer to the OP. this one is really meant more for future visitors who know a bit more about the classes and algorithms and want to accomplish this.